# Add timer to hide function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add a timer to my hide function, How will I do that? Here is the code:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.snackbar').slideUp(600, function(){
               $(this).hide();
            }); 
})
```

Comment: Second param of `setTimeout` is time it takes for it to execute in milliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of the `setTimeout` call is the number of milliseconds to wait before executing the function (the first parameter).

To wait 500 milliseconds (for example) before running your function, you would do this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.snackbar').slideUp(600, function(){
        $(this).hide();
    }); 
}, 500); // change this number to change the time waited before executing the function
```

Comment: No that's the speed it takes to go off the screen

Comment: No, it's not. The `600` as the first parameter of the `slideUp` function is the speed of that. `setTimeout` executes the function in parameter 1 after waiting the number of milliseconds in parameter 2. In my example above, it will run your function after 500 milliseconds.

Comment: Worked perfectly!! Thanks

Comment: Please don't forget to click the tick icon next to my answer to mark it as your chosen answer.

Comment: sure waiting for 8 min lol